# Drupal 7 menu alter

Tags: drupal, menu, preprocessor, hook

I got a Drupal 7 menu, machine name is "main-menu".

Every 3 `li` tags I want to add a wrapper to manipulate with CSS.

I'm already doing it with jQuery slice but on page load final result is not what I expected.

I can do that in a normal template but most likely I need to preprocess the menu in template.php and I actually don't know what to do.

Is there someone to help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may want to use [theme_menu_link](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7)
Or maybe you can do what you need with the [:nth-child](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) CSS selector.

Comment: Solved this using css :nth child selector. Didn't find away to use Drupal theme_menu_link to do that.